# Minimize number of copied sub-dependencies (assemblies) by only referencing parts of a class library?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference, dependencies

I have a .Net class library that contains many different namespaces and multiple sub-dependencies (referenced assemblies).

Sometimes a project references only one specific namespace, sometimes just one single interface, of such class library but still upon compilation all sub-dependencies (dlls) are copied into my project assembly folder (\bin folder).

So if class library `MainClassLibrary` references `subLib1`, `sublib2`, and `sublib3` and when I create a new `project` that references `MainClassLibrary` then `subLib1.dll`, `subLib2.dll`, and `subLib3.dll` are also all copied into the binary folder of my `project` even if I only use an interface definition in a segregated namespace within `MainLibrary` that does not depend on any of the sub dependencies.

Is the only way to split up the class library into smaller pieces or is there a better, easier way?

Comment: Side note: usually "dll hell" means almost opposite problem...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, could you please suggest a suitable name then?

Comment: Not really... Maybe just "Minimize set of DLLs ..." but it less noticeable than "Avoid 'dll hell' by..." plus you have it quotes as indirect meaning... Just keep in mind that what you are talking about is not [DLL hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) but rather solution to it :)

Comment: This is a problem that is created an might  be solved by the design of the Library, it all depends on its granularity. It is not something a consuming App can solve.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, would you have any link or reference that covers this topic? The class library contains core objects but also provides messaging/charting/math algorithm functionality that is only occasionally used/referenced.

Comment: @MattWolf - Try to extract an example of _"that is only occasionally used/referenced"_.  Much easier to discuss this for a specific case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, well as stated, an interface that I use for C# scripting purposes is part of the larger class library (one of my core toolboxes so to speak) but obviously only used when I deal with scripts. Yet, when I occasionally write a project dealing with such, all other assemblies are copied as well, such as messaging libraries and their assemblies....

Comment: Still not very concrete but usually a Script engine depends on everything that might be scripted.

Comment: ...sure but that won't affect the actual issue under discussion would it? I am not sure into how much more detail I could go while at the same time adding value. Are you trying to get an idea how/where to logically delineate use cases?

Answer (score 2):

> even if I only use an interface definition in a segregated namespace within MainLibrary

That is the reason that sometimes only one or a handful of interfaces are put into a separate assembly (Project).

But in general, focus on minimizing the logical dependencies and don't worry to much about how many DLL files are copied.

And as @Alexei mentioned in  his comment, this (automated) proliferation of DLL files is the *solution* to DLL Hell.

Comment: got it re "dll hell", thanks for explaining, so the going practice is essentially to intelligently split up the library into smaller pieces then?

Comment: Yes, but more along logical concerns. Less files to copy is a side-effect, not a target.